# Python socket getaddrinfo gives result but requests gives dns_unresolved_hostname

Tags: python, python-requests, dns

I don't really understand what's going on here and I don't know how to troubleshoot further. This is what I'm doing on a tooling server running Windows Server 2019:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import socket
>>> print(socket.getaddrinfo('myurl.test', 1414))
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('10.140.11.11', 1414))]
>>> url ='http://myurl.test:1414/testing'
>>> body = '{"dateTime": "2022-07-11T16:45:52.633840","testcase": "1"}'
>>> h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
>>> response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers = h)
>>> response.text
'<HTML><HEAD>\r\n <TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>\r\n </HEAD>\r\n <BODY>\r\n <FONT face="Helvetica">\r\n <big><strong></strong></big><BR>\r\n </FONT>\r\n <blockquote>\r\n <TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">\r\n <TR><TD>\r\n <FONT face="Helvetica">\r\n <big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>\r\n <BR>\r\n <BR>\r\n </FONT>\r\n </TD></TR>\r\n <TR><TD>\r\n <FONT face="Helvetica">\r\n Your requested host "myurl.test" could not be resolved by DNS.\r\n </FONT>\r\n </TD></TR>\r\n <TR><TD>\r\n <FONT face="Helvetica">\r\n \r\n </FONT>\r\n </TD></TR>\r\n <TR><TD>\r\n <FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>\r\n <BR>\r\n For assistance, contact your network support team.\r\n </FONT>\r\n </TD></TR>\r\n </TABLE>\r\n </blockquote>\r\n </FONT>\r\n </BODY></HTML>\r\n'
```

the socket.getaddrinfo shows the correct IP-address and port from the hosts file, but when I use the requests module, I get a dns_unresolved_hostname. The weird things are:

- if I do a curl command from the commandline, it works
- this works for me in python on another (test) tooling server with a slightly different endpoint
- there is one user who does not get a 404 but gets a valid response if he runs the steps above

I cannot find anything wrong in the hosts file, proxy settings or the environment variables.

Comment: "but when I use the requests module, I get a dns_unresolved_hostname" That is not exactly true. `requests` works perfectly for your URL, connects, and get back a reply! The content of the reply is under control of your webserver at host `myurl.test` on port 1414. For some reason it seems this webserver does not recognize `myurl.test` as a name it is handling. In short your problem is not DNS related, but only related to the configuration of this webserver and what you want it to do.

Comment: "the correct IP-address and port from the hosts file" does the server at 10.140.11.11 have the same information in its own hosts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to check the requests module and found out it was retrieving the proxyEnable and proxyOverride settings from the users registry. These were filled with wrong values in the registry (even though these settings do not show if you open Proxy Settings in Windows!). I think what happened is: users had a manual proxy enabled, then switched to an automatic proxy setup. But requests still looks at the registry even though these settings are disabled for the user.

I updated the registry by removing the proxyEnable and adjusting the proxyOverride, and now the python script works for everyone!